# VBA Excel For Each Loop

Tags: excel, foreach, pi-db, vba

The nested loops should take a point and find its description and write it into another column. The problem I have is only the value from `B20` is written into `C10:C20`. If I change the fourth line to `b.value`, it works correctly for the output but in the wrong column so I believe it's a looping issue but I don't see the solution.

```
For Each b In Worksheets("Device").Range("B10:B20").Cells
    For Each c In Worksheets("Device").Range("C10:C20").Cells
        Set pt = srv.PIPoints(b.Value)
        c.Value = pt.PointAttributes.Item("descriptor")
    Next
Next
```

Comment: You are looping over all C cells for each of the B cells. That's probably not what you intended to do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this one instead:

```
For Each b in WorkSheets("Device").Range("B10:B20").Cells   
    Set pt = srv.PIPoints(b.Value)
    b.Offset(,1).Value = pt.PointAttributes.Item("descriptor")
Next
```

where `b.Offset(,1)` gives you cell one column to the right from `b`, i.e. if `b` points to `B11` then `b.Offset(,1)` points to `C11`

Comment: That worked, I did not think about doing it by offset